# Server can't find example.com: NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I am having trouble setting up a local DNS server with forward and reverse zones.

> Resolv.conf

```
search myco.nmm6145.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
```

> named.conf

```
options {
    directory "/var/named";
    listen-on port 53 {any;};
    allow-query {localhost;};
    allow-transfer {any;};
    empty-zones-enable no;
    recursion yes;
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

zone "."            { type hint;    file "named.ca";    allow-query {any;};};
zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa."    { type master;  file "db.127.0.0";  allow-query{any;};};
zone "myco.nmm6145.com"     { type master;  file "db.myco";     allow-query{any;};};
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa."  { type master;  file "db.192.168.1"; };
zone "20.168.192.in-addr.arpa." { type master;  file "db.192.168.20"; };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

> db.myco

```
$TTL 86400
@   SOA linserv.nmm6145.com hostmaster ( 2003080800 12h 15m 3w 3h )

; IAM NAME SERVER
    IN NS   linserv.nmm6145.com.
    IN NS   winserv.nmm6145.com.

; Canonical names
; More may need to be defined as the DNS group grows
localhost       A   127.0.0.1
linserv     IN  A   192.168.1.1
winserv     IN  A   192.168.1.2

; No Aliases yet
www     IN  CNAME   winclient

;No interface spec. names yet
```

> db.192.168.20

```
$TTL 86400
;$ORIGIN 20.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@   IN SOA  linserv.nmm6145.com hostmaster.myco.nmm6145.com. ( 2003080700 3h 15m 3w 3h )

;NS
@   IN NS   linserv.nmm6145.com.
@   IN NS   winserv.nmm6145.com.
@   IN PTR  nmm6145.com.

;Addr
linserv IN A    192.168.1.1
winserv IN A    192.168.1.2

;PTR
2   IN PTR  winserv.nmm6145.com.
1   IN PTR  linserv.nmm6145.com.
```

> db.192.168.1

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@   SOA linserv.nmm6145.com hostmaster.myco.nmm6145.com. ( 2003080600 3h 15m 3w 3h )

;NS
@   IN NS   linserv.nmm6145.com.
@   IN NS   winserv.nmm6145.com.
@   IN PTR  nmm6145.com

linserv IN A    192.168.1.1
winserv IN A    192.168.1.2

;PTR
192.168.1.1 IN PTR  linserv.nmm6145.com.
192.168.1.2 IN PTR  winserv.nmm6145.com.
```

> db.127.0.0

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN 0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.
@   IN SOA  linserv.nmm6145.com hostmaster.myco.nmm6145.com ( 2003080500 3h 15m 3w 3h )

; Define Name Server
    IN NS   linserv.nmm6145.com.
    IN NS   winserv.nmm6145.com.

; Give localhost ptr
1   IN PTR      localhost.

;Hostname to Address
;linserv IN A       127.0.0.1
```

Here are some commands I have run to diagnose the issue:

> nslookup @localhost linserv.myco.nmm6145.com

```
;;Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.122.1, trying next server
```

Unsure where the 122 subnet comes into play here, can't seem to find it on any of my zone or config files.

> dig nmm6145

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 16519
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;; nmm6145. IN A

;;SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
```

I have also tried to flush my cache via

> $rndc flush

Comment: Stop and uninstall the libvirt service (and KVM).